# Is it possible to create simple frontend for use with Virtocommerce without writing liquid pages

Tags: virtocommerce

I am evaluating Virtocommerce for a small startup company.  We only have a few products and would like to make use of VC's user and payment modules instead of creating a website ourselves from scratch.  We are familiar with asp.net mvc, angularjs and RestAPI. However, we would rather not learn and use the liquid theme engine if all possible.

So the question is, is it possible/a good idea to simply create a angularjs web app and call storefront's RestAPI?   Please advice.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course, it is possible, you even can exclude `VirtoCommerce.LiquidThemeEngine` project from storefront solution and use ASP.NET razor views for the rendering  SEO critical pages and use client SPA for another kind of presentation logic.

We have some clients who use this kind of storefront implementation (without Liquid themes) but unfortunately, I couldn't provide any of these examples because they aren't in a public access.

If you will have more questions you might ask them in our community chat [gitter VirtoCommerce/vc-platform](https://gitter.im/VirtoCommerce/vc-platform)